# Why is FileInputStream so slow?

Tags: java, linux, inputstream

I'm using `RHEL7`.

I'm working on an application which is supposed to load large amount of data from the outside. I have `ramdisk` which is stored inside the `RAM` and is supposed to be read very fast. I access it in two ways:

1. `FileInputStream`

   ```
   public static void main(String [] args){
       try(InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/mnt/ramdisk/file"))
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis))){

            while(//till the end of stream
                  ){
                byte[] buffer = new byte[_some_size_];
                r.read(buffer);
                //Do something useful
            }
   }
   ```
2. Read through `System.in`. `cat ramdisk/file | java -cp my.jar com.test.Main`

   ```
   The same as 1, but the stream is System.in.
   ```

The second way is much faster. On my machine in works about 7 times faster than the first one.

Can someone explain the performance difference? I would like to understand it.

Comment: Please share your code. We cannot tell you what's wrong without seeing how you are reading the stream (Either with `FileInputStream` or `System.in`). Also, how can you read in-memory contents with `FileInputStream`?

Comment: @BackSlash Very easy. Just create RAM disk.

Comment: Ok, what about the first point? Can you please share your code?

Comment: @BackSlash Done

Comment: You shouldn't allocate a new array in every iteration, and you can't read a byte[] from a Reader (i.e., you are being inaccurate about relevant details)

Comment: System.in is abstract. What is the actual instance?

Comment: @efekctive System.in is a public field.

Comment: @efekctive - it is a class provided by the standard class libraries.

Comment: That is clear. But you are asking to compare pears and apples without knowing what you are actually comparing. Make the effort. Then you will find the answer yourself

Comment: And you probably are thinking about memory mapped files. Then you would need to look into nio. All of the above will be limited to memory constraints